# Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY, Realm and JSON

Tags: android, json, realm, picasso

I have write JSON file:

```
[
{ "name"  : "Sir",
  "votes" : 23,
  "imageURL"  : "http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/5ogv5yJ.png" },

{ "name"  : "Bar",
  "votes" : 21,
  "imageURL"  : [
                    "http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/G1qQb9Q.png",
                    "http://www.dreamhost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DHC_blog-image-01-300x300.jpg",
                    "http://lh5.ggpht.com/yt6SnO_2jOIot1FhQYGiVXd_IQWBOCmQ1UJBddyau3Wzw1ZgpdeQwpO7TRFnux3Dirk=w300",
                    "http://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/4728693_300x300.jpg",
                    "http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/themes/mind-control/images/octocat.jpg"
  ]
},

{ "name"  : "Buildings",
  "votes" : 19,
  "imageURL"  : "http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/brzudoL.png"}
```

]

Model class

```
public class City extends RealmObject {

private String name;
private long votes;
private String imageURL;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getVotes() {
    return votes;
}

public void setVotes(long votes) {
    this.votes = votes;
}

public String getImageURL() {
    return imageURL;
}

public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}
```

}

And Adapter

```
public class CityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//private final Context context;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<City> cities = null;
```

/* public CityAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context; */

```
public CityAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void setData(List<City> details) {
    this.cities = details;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (cities == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return cities.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (cities == null || cities.get(position) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return cities.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View currentView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (currentView == null) {
        currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_listitem, parent, false);
    }

    City city = cities.get(position);
    ImageView photo = (ImageView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.picture);

    if (city != null) {

        Picasso.with(inflater.getContext()).load(city.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.internet_access_placeholder).into(photo);

        ((TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(city.getName());
        ((TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.votes)).setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", city.getVotes()));
    }

    return currentView;
}
```

}

down there in adapter I setup picasso:

```
Picasso.with(inflater.getContext()).load(city.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.internet_access_placeholder).into(photo);
```

And project is working when I got only one photo in JSON like image from object "name" : "Sir"

But When I write multiple URLs like in 2nd object "name" : "Bar" I get that error: "Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY"

I understand what is problem but I don't know how to fix it...
I want to have more than one photo in some objects like in 2nd

Answer (score 0):

then always expect / send an array and map it to a list and check for the list size

```
final List<String> urls = city.getImageURLs(); 
if (urls.size() > 1) {
    // add code for more images
} else {
    Picasso.with(inflater.getContext()).load(urls.get(0)).placeholder(R.drawable.internet_access_placeholder).into(photo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

imageURL must be Json array

```
[
{ "name"  : "Sir",
  "votes" : 23,
  "imageURL"  : [ "http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/5ogv5yJ.png" ] },

{ "name"  : "Bar",
  "votes" : 21,
  "imageURL"  : [
                    "http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/G1qQb9Q.png",
                    "http://www.dreamhost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DHC_blog-image-01-300x300.jpg",
                    "http://lh5.ggpht.com/yt6SnO_2jOIot1FhQYGiVXd_IQWBOCmQ1UJBddyau3Wzw1ZgpdeQwpO7TRFnux3Dirk=w300",
                    "http://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/4728693_300x300.jpg",
                    "http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/themes/mind-control/images/octocat.jpg"
  ]
}
]
```

and your model must be like that

```
public class City extends RealmObject {

private String name;
private long votes;
private List<String> imageURL;

   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps...
How should looks my adapter now?